# Correlations vs. negligence of correlations in covariance matrix

Tags: error-analysis, statistics, covariance, models

Suppose I have a model composed of two parameters $(a,b)$ that I want to describe a set of data points with. In CASE A, I fit the model taking into consideration the correlations between the data points (that is, in the chi square formulation I use the full covariance matrix for the data) and in CASE B I only use the diagonal covariance matrix (that is, off diagonal elements are set to zero, so I neglect the correlations).

Is it a general feature that I may expect different results for the best fit parameters $(a,b)$ in each analysis? If so, why? If not, why not?

Comment: Most stat. tools assume stat. independence, because they are not applicable if correlation exists. Hence, most often there exists a difference between the two results. However, your question is so vague that it is not answerable. What is your model?

Comment: @Semoi I am fitting a power form, $y = ax^b$. Data points are labelled as $(x_i, y_i)$ so model prediction for point $x_i$ is $ax_i^b$.

Comment: I agree with probably_someone answer: We absolutely expect that the fit result changes. The fit result minimises the variance of the dataset, and the variance of the dataset is influenced by the correlation. However, please consider using a log-transformation prior to the fit. Most often it is a bad idea to fit the power law, because one obtain "non homogeneous" variances. So check your model assumptions.

Comment: @Semoi Thank you. I wonder about the extent of the difference between the values of the parameters obtained using a) the covariance matrix and b) the diagonal version? Because if they differ dramatically, then the two estimates for the parameters would give two curves which may also differ dramatically and then it becomes possible to eye ball the better fit in a plot showing the data points and their 1 sigma standard deviations (which do not depend on whether one switches the diagonal elements to zero or not).

Comment: If you like to get a "feeling", how the correlation changes the result, it is usually a good idea to simulate data with different correlation coeffs.

Comment: @Semoi sure indeed, will do. But I was just thinking conceptually at this point - I mean if the best fit mean values change a lot then this will be reflected in the curve one plots. So I would imagine the difference may only be in the decimal points of a result.

Answer (score 1):

If the uncertainties on every data point are completely uncorrelated from those on every other data point, then your covariance matrix will be diagonal. If there is *any pair of points* for which this is not true, your covariance matrix will not be diagonal.

If you know your covariance matrix is not diagonal, and choose to set the off-diagonal elements to zero, you are feeding your fitter inaccurate uncertainties. This can certainly cause the conclusions of the fit to change.

This is intuitive if you look at extreme cases. Suppose the uncertainty of every point is perfectly correlated with every other point, so the effect of uncertainty is to move all of the points up or down together, without changing the difference between any two of them. Given this, suppose you're applying a linear fit to some data that is roughly linear. The uncertainty on the fitted slope of the line will be much lower if you don't ignore correlations than if you assume that all of the uncertanties are uncorrelated (in short: if the uncertainty cannot change the difference between any two points, then any displacement caused by that uncertainty cannot change the slope of the line). If you ignore correlations, you risk, at the very least, underestimating the precision of your analysis. In more complicated cases, you could also affect the central values of the fit parameters as well.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Few comments: a) May there be cases where negligence of the correlations causes the error to instead be overestimated rather than underestimated? Anti correlations? b) Typically, when one plots data points, the error bars shown are the standard deviations (square root of the total diagonal elements). So these values are the same regardless of whether one puts the off diagonal elements to zero or not. So I just wondered what more complicated situations you mentioned would allow one to obtain different best fit parameters by including correlations?